# Current (.NET 4) way to send an XML request to a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0

What is the most current (.NET 4) way to send a raw XML request to a web service?  Does it differ between asmx and wcf services?

I want to build XML via a front-end interface and have the ability to send it to different endpoints.  These endpoints could be asmx or wcf.  What is the best approach to get started doing this?

Comment: Can you share why you want to send raw xml? I've been working on a smiliar project lately (few w-services i needed to call with xml-based data), and we ended up wrapping it all in DataContracts. I think xml should remain as one of the ways to serialize/pass data between systems, and not THE format you work with on higher levels, especially when in .NET you have so many tools to serialize/deserialize xml to classes.

Comment: I guess my definition of raw XML is not correct.  What I mean is just sending plain old XML just like if I were to paste it into SOAPUI and send it to an endpoint.  Does this make sense?  I have heard of using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, but is this still the most current way?

Comment: it should still be WCF data service

Answer (score 0):

I think we mean the same thing; I usually prefer not just to send XML but to work with objects and let the WCF engine to decide in what format itll pass it to the service/client (which might depend on the protocls you and your service providers support). In the terms of WCF, it means defining classes as [Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx), and working with their instances only, and not the XML they might represent. 

If the other side supports ASMX only, it limits the supported protocols WCF can use to work against to  WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 (if Im not mistaken with this), but whatever technology You choose/work against, the concept, in my opinion, should remain the same: in .NET work with classes, and let the underlying communication technology to decide how to serialize and pass it to the other side. Of course, its also more secure than just to send raw string as xml (though you can probably solve some of the security issues by validating against a schema the received xml)